# Impedir múltiplos cliques em Android

Tags: android

Possuo uma tela de cadastro de usuários onde evito a possibilidade de múltiplos cliques ao botão cadastrar por meio do método [**View.setEnabled()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled(boolean)). Procedo da seguinte forma: no método [**onClick()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html#onClick(android.view.View)), da interface View.OnClickListener, desabilito o botão e, após o fim da requisição, no método **[onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result))** da AsyncTask o habilito novamente.

Embora seja uma solução simples, li no [SO americano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9950832/2788975) que esta solução não resolve de forma adequada o problema. Na resposta dada nesta thread o autor cita o fato de que os clicks ficam numa fila para serem executados posteriormente.

Diante do fato destacado pergunto: a solução adotada no SO americano é a solução final para resolver o problema ou existe uma solução melhor ou ideal para resolvê-lo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, esse problema ocorre pelo fato dele postergar a detecção de click usando o `post` e `postDelayed`, e isso vai enfileirar os eventos de `ACTION_UP`. Isso pode ser visto pelo código fonte da classe `View`:

```
// Use a Runnable and post this rather than calling
// performClick directly. This lets other visual state
// of the view update before click actions start.
if (mPerformClick == null) {
    mPerformClick = new PerformClick();
}

if (!post(mPerformClick)) {
    performClick();
}
```

Não consigo pensar numa forma melhor de fazer, a flag é suficiente.

Mas acho que da para melhorar um pouco isso, fazendo com que essa lógica fique centralizada em uma subclasse do `Button`. Assim você evita a replicação de código, e deixa transparente para quem usa. Ainda seria preciso setar o `setEnabled` por causa do processamento assíncrono, caso contrário basta fazer a gerência da flag `enabled` antes e depois da chamada do `performClick` do pai (`super`).

Minha sugestão seria:

```
public class SingleClickButton extends Button {
    public SingleClickButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SingleClickButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SingleClickButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public SingleClickButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        return isEnabled() && super.performClick();
    }
}
```

Essa solução ainda irá enfileirar os eventos, mas não deixará executar repetidamente. Para evitar o acumulo de eventos, teria que haver a sobreescrita do `onTouchEvent`, mas é uma abordagem mais agressiva e acho que desnecessária.

Para usar em um layout seu, basta declarar a tag com o caminho inteiro do pacote e da classe:

```
<nome.do.seu.pacote.SingleClickButton
    ...
/>
```

Comment: Olá, Walkin. De que forma posso fazer uso dessa solução apresentada por você? Como fazer o botão de minha view fazer uso dessa subclasse?

Comment: Você precisaria trocar o `Button` no xml por `nome.do.seu.pacote.SingleClickButton`, para usar essa subclasse.

Answer (score -2):

Você deve condicionar o seu botão usando if ou when. Nessa condição (if ou when), defina: "botao.isEnabled = false". No entanto, para que isso funcione, esse trecho de código deve estar em uma posição adequada dentro da condição.
Meu exemplo:
[image: Print]

• Se eu implementar a condição após "informeSeuNome.length() != 0", o botão continuaria sendo clicável.